# Dynamic keys when using Django filter()

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a function that takes an object, and what I would like to do is be able to filter by this obj and delete the queryset result.

I tried this, but it doesn't work because `model_obj.__class__._meta.model_name` finds the name of a word **one model** such as `Profile`, but if I have a model called: `ProfileLogin`, the result will be `profilelogin`, but it should be `profile_login`.

```
def delete_profile_from_obj(obj):

     filter_by = model_obj.__class__._meta.model_name

     kwargs = {
         filter_by: obj  
     }


     profiles = Profile.objects.filter(**kwargs)
     profiles.delete()
```

`Profile` has a one-to-many relationship with the `obj` passed into the function.

Comment: Am I correct that Profile model has N fields containing nullable links (not FKs) to N models? And please describe your original intent/task/why are you doing this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get relationship model name of object Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326533/get-relationship-model-name-of-object-django)