# Get relationship model name of object Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to get the model name for different objects:

This kinda works:

```
last_profile = Profile.object.last()

profile.__class__._meta.verbose_name // 'profile'
```

But not for a compounded model name such `ProfileLogin`:

```
last_profile_login = ProfileLogin.objects.last()
last_profile_login.__class__._meta.verbose_name // 'profile login'
```

I would like the last example to be `profile_login`.

The reason, I'm doing this is to create a dynamic query using filter().

Comment: does `print(ProfileLogin._meta.model_name)` work? what filter are you trying to perform?

Comment: @RHSmith159 this gives me `profilelogin` not `profile_login` :(

Comment: You mean that, you want to get class name am i right?

Comment: Please show your model definition.

Comment: @kamilyrb correct! because, I want to use this model_name in my filter() dynamically

Comment: Could you try this `profile.__class__.__name`